# Minimum amount of points required to find a transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Given a set of point $P$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and the same set of points $P'$ which have been transformed by a transformation matrix:
$$L: \mathbb R^n\mapsto \mathbb R^n$$ 
$$L(p_1) = p_1',\;\; p_1\in P\land p_1 '\in P'$$
What is the minimum amount of point pairs ($p_1,p_1'$) required to find $L$ for a given $n$?
And what are the requirements for these points?

I think they should not lie on one line or plane (depending on $n$)

Comment: You need at least $n^2$ points to completly determinate the matrix of L

Comment: Why? Do you have proof for that?

Comment: The idea is that each point gives you a linear equation with unknow the matrix coefficients ($n^2$ unknow). Then the system has at most one solution if there is at least $n^2$ equations

Comment: Each point will yield $n$ equations though; thus, you only need $n$ of them. In particular, evaluating $L$ on a basis of $R^n$ will completely determine the coefficients in the matrix. Even easier is to use the standard basis $e_1 = (1,0,0,\dots,0)$, etc., the system of equations is particularly simple in this case; $l_{ij} = (Le_j)_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need $n$ linearly independent points in $\mathbb R^n$ to determine $L$. If you know what $L$ does to a set $P$ of points in $\mathbb R^n$ then linearity tells you what $L$ does to every linear combination of points in $P$. The space $\mathbb R^n$ has sets of $n$ linearly independent points but not any sets of more than $n$ points. If you pick $k<n$ pairs of points then there will be sets of at least $n-k$ points in $\mathbb R^n$ for which $L$ is not determined and we won't know what the transformation does. If you pick $k>n$ pairs of points, then some will be linearly dependent and thus either redundant or contradictory.

Comment: So the only requirement is that they should be linearly independent? What if one of the points is in the origin of the space? And when are redundant pairs 'contradictory'?

Comment: Linear independence requires you not pick the origin. It isn't linearly independent from any other point (or even from itself) -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence
Contradictions arise if transformed points don't agree with the linearity of the matrix. This is usually called "overdetermined"
-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system